# Making csv file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have two different textfiles.txt (textfile1.txt and textfile2.txt) with different data sets in them. Is it possible to compile two seperate .txt files as a single CSV file?

**UPDATE**

textfile1.txt has values written in this format:

```
 20
 31
 18
 -11
 12
 19
```

textfile2.txt has values written in this format:

```
100.000 200.000 300.000
101.000 201.000 301.000
102.000 202.000 302.000
103.000 203.000 303.000
104.000 204.000 304.000
105.000 205.000 305.000
```

I wish for my output to be in following format:

```
 20,100.000,200.000,300.000
 31,101.000,201.000,-301.000
 18,-102.000,202.000,302.000
-11,103.000,203.000,303.000
 12,104.000,204.000,304.000
 19,105.000,-205.000,305.000
```

Comment: Are the two text files CSVs themselves?

Comment: Yes it is, but in order for us to help you, you need to show us an example of your files and the output you would like to see. How exactly should they be combined? Should file2 be added to file1? Should line1 of file2 be added to line1 of file1? [Edit] your question to clarify it and it can be reopened.

Comment: Just a suggestion - to clarify the transformation - could you show textfile1.txt with different numbers in it? Or are they always 20?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Just updated it to make it clearer. Hope this helps~

Answer (score 3):

`paste` will join files side by side

```
paste -d, file1 file2
```

if the files may contain commas or quotes but are not CSV data themselves, they will need to all be quoted first.

```
paste -d, \
 $<( sed 's/"/""/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"' < file1 ) \
 $<( sed 's/"/""/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"' < file1 )
```

or only the lines containing the special characters

```
paste -d, \
 $<( sed '/[",]/ { s/"/""/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"; }' < file1 ) \
 $<( sed '/[",]/ { s/"/""/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"; }' < file2 )
```

Comment: since the 2nd textfile is not comma-separated, you would need some postprocessing even in the simplest forum: e.g. `paste -d, file1 file2 | sed -e 's|  *|, |g'`

Comment: @umläute, perhaps `sed -e 's/  */,/g' file2 | paste -d, file1 -` is better (fix up input). Careful, it is *two* spaces before `*`

Comment: @vonbrand good point

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is combine the two files then `cat textfile1.txt textfile2.txt > combined.txt` will do that.

Comment: I wish to combine the two files and convert the result to a CSV file, where the information of textfile1.txt and textfile2.txt are in seperate columns.

Comment: @JolyDroneSP that detail should be added to the question,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the second file uses tabs as delimiters, then you may append the first file as a first column to the second file using

```bash
paste textfile1.txt textfile2.txt
```

The result would be a TSV data set (assuming the data contains no fields with embedded newlines):

```
20      100.000 200.000 300.000
31      101.000 201.000 301.000
18      102.000 202.000 302.000
-11     103.000 203.000 303.000
12      104.000 204.000 304.000
19      105.000 205.000 305.000
```

To convert this into CSV, you may simply change any tabs into commas using `tr '\t' ','`, or, if you have more complicated data (embedded tabs) use a CSV-aware tool such as Miller (`mlr`):

```bash
paste textfile1.txt textfile2.txt |
mlr --itsv --ocsv cat
```

The option `--itsv` (input is TSV) in combination with `--ocsv` (output is CSV) may be combined into the single option `--t2c`.